# Am I allowed to name a game after some song?

Tags: legal

Just to ask a quick question, which I don't know where to ask: If I were to make a game, would I be allowed to call it "Buffalo Soldier [some more words]"? Since it's a song by Bob Marley I am not sure if this would get me into all kinds of legal trouble because of copyrights, which I obviously want to avoid.

By the way, the game doesn't have anything to do with Bob Marley or the music industry. I just thought a game about a buffalo soldier would be nice!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

Of course, only *your* lawyer can advise you of *your* legal risk in civil matters like this. However, a reasonable person should not be at risk of brand confusion - which is the question a court would have to answer in that case, as this more aptly falls under trademark which protects symbols identifying things with business value, as opposed copyright which protects the content.

Comment: Even outside of brand confusion, if there's an impression that the game is profiting from the association with another artist's work, there exists some possibility of challenge - see the "Californication" lawsuit, for example.

Comment: Note that "Buffalo Soldier" is a widely known historical term that Marely was basing his own song off of. Unless the game has any reference to Marely, there's no confusion.

Comment: There's always a possibility of challenge, as noted. Civil courts are well known entertainers of frivolity on litigants' pocketbooks. There are plenty of lawsuits just like RHCP v Showtime, and it's an apt comparison given D demonstrated the term "Californication" was also common parlance prior to RHCP publishing the song.

Comment: Does this apply only to the US or is there an international copyright law?

Comment: If you mean one law governing all IP issues around the world, no. Each country has its own treaties which it may or may not enforce. This is *probably* still true for most other common law countries (Canada, Australia, and UK being the main examples) while countries with different legal systems (Japan, China, South Korea...) may have radically different interpretations.

Comment: It's usually just better to check each country individually - which is why some things are only sold in certain countries; to protect the seller from possible legal trouble.